# Rdlc report viewer in not shwoing report in a WPF applicaiton

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

I am trying to view a rdlc report in a WPF application I have used the WindowsFormHost to host the rdlc report viewer but when i run the application no error at all but also noting is showing in report-viewer not even the report-viewer is showing.
Here is the xaml code

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost" Grid.Row="2" >
            <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
```

And the c# code for report loading

```
 List<Furniture> Purchases = null;
            using (IDbConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    db.Open();
                }
                string Command = "Select I.Id,I.Title,I.Category,I.Description,I.VoucherNumber,I.Cost,I.PurchasedDate,B.Title AS BudgetHead,D.Name AS Distributer, F.Type,F.Color,F.Condition,I.Status,I.CreatedBy FROM Items I INNER JOIN Furniture F ON I.Id=F.EntryId INNER JOIN BudgetHeads B ON I.BudgetHeadId=B.Id INNER JOIN Distributers D ON I.DistributerId=D.Id";
                Purchases = db.Query<Furniture>(Command,null, commandType: CommandType.Text).ToList();
            }
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            var DataSource = new ReportDataSource() { Name = "FurnitureDataSource", Value = Purchases };
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DataSource);
            string Path = @"D:\ADiTM\Products\Stock Management\Software\Reports\Purchase.rdlc";
            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path;
            reportViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            reportViewer.Refresh();
            reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: i think you are missing the `reportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Normal)`

Comment: @styx I have used the display mode but still not working,as i mentioned in the question not even the report-viewer is showing

Comment: did you initialize the `DataContext` in your window?

Comment: I have that the problem is with the windows host, which is not showing at run-time and  have even added a simple MaskedTextBox to check but it is not that as well in run-time. Can any one please comment?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, actually the allow transparency was set to true in main window which s causing the windows host not showing any thing at run-time.